# Mpdf table not taking full width though putting inline width

Tags: php, mpdf

Printing a table with 795 rows and three column like category, sub category, questions. Grouping categories and subcategories using rowspan. And every categories contains more than 150 questions. In every other table with fewer data printing perfectly but this table with 795 data not printing with full width though using inline css. Please help how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your query, I suspect you are try to print the table with 100% with. Please try the below code

```
$html = '<table width="100%">
             <tr>
                 <td>....</td>
                 <td>....</td>
                 <td>....</td> 
             </tr>
              .....
              .....
          </table>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Comment: These are fine but my table contains 795 rows and first td has rowspan of 209 and second td has 48 rowspan. Then next row accordingly

Comment: Yes mentioned properly. In html view it's perfect.

Comment: Post  your HTML Code

Comment: It's a bit private. Will post table with similar data later on

Comment: Ok. If have use 'width' in any <td> or <th> please remove it.. You just use width 100% with in <table> alone, sure it will work.

Comment: But th width needed as per requirement for custom width per column. Still I will try